# Django haystack The model <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'> is not registered

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm trying to setup haystack with django but I get this error, I've googled it and it's not been reported yet. I think it would be related to the index so I did an update_index and makemigrations and migrate but it hasn't solved the issue.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://kbuzz.webfactional.com/rest/movies/?device=browser

Django Version: 1.7.10
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'djangorestframework',
 'haystack',
 'lamusoftware.generic',
 'mptt',
 'bootstrapform',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'oauth2client',
 'articles',
 'banners',
 'common',
 'directory',
 'events',
 'galleries',
 'marketplace',
 'movies',
 'pages',
 'profiles',
 'search',
 'stats',
 'minidetector',
 'mobile',
 'reports',
 'favorites',
 'braces',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'wordofmouth',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_mobile',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'markup_deprecated',
 'whoosh')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.RedirectMovie')


Traceback:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/views.py" in dispatch
  228.             response_obj = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/rest/views.py" in get
  238.             search_index = connections['default'].get_unified_index().get_index(get_model(*self.django_model.split('.')))
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/utils/loading.py" in get_index
  283.             raise NotHandled('The model %s is not registered' % model_klass.__class__)

Exception Type: NotHandled at /rest/movies/
Exception Value: The model <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'> is not registered
```

Comment: Need more info to help you. Can you post your defintion of the index you are trying to use together with the code for the view?